# How can I create a background image using css in this CMS generated html structure?

Tags: css

I'm using Drupal views and have it set to display a content body and an image field. The html structure generated is

```
<div>
     <span>  content body </span>
     <span class='background-image'> <img src= my-image-address > </span>
```

I would like to place the image as the background image within the div, if possible using CSS.  The display places the image below the content body.  Is there a way to restyle this as the div background?

Comment: Is this a question about CSS or Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Not using plain old CSS, but if you can throw some jQuery into the mix, you could set it by targeting `$('.background-image').parent('div')` and either use `.css()` or add a class with `.addClass()` on the parent `<div>`.

Comment: Is there css that will have the browser treat it as a background image?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Are you asking for the CSS code to add a background image to an element?